# INSERT prepared statement PDO + WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got a script,`script1.php` to get data out of my database and a script which is almost the same but with a search option `script2.php` to search in my database.

In `script1.php`when I press the delete button or the profile button I get the required results. Line gets deleted or I get a profile with the data from that specific line.

In `script2.php` when I press the delete button my line gets deleted but than I get no more results while with script 1 all the results stay on the page. The profile button is not working at all and I don't understand why. I would appriciated a good explination so I now for the future.

Script1

```
<head>
<title>AJ Recruit - Kandidaten Database</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<label>AJ Recruit - Kandidaten Database</label>
</div>
<div id="body">
    <table width="80%" border="1">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="9"><form action="search.php" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="query" />
        <input type="submit" value="Zoek" />
    </form></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="9"><label><a href="test.php">Voeg nieuwe kandidaat toe</a></label></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>geslacht</td>
    <td>Voornaam</td>
    <td>Familienaam</td>
    <td>email</td>
    <td>Telefoon</td>
    <td>Bekijk CV</td>
    <td>Datum</td>
    <td>Profiel</td>
    <td>Verwijder</td>

    </tr>
<?php

$servername = "xxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxx";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, geslacht, voornaam, familienaam, email, tel, afile, app_datum FROM sollicitatie_form"); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':geslacht', $geslacht,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':voornaam', $voornaam,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':familienaam', $familienaam,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tel', $tel,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tel', $afile,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':app_datum', $app_datum,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach ($result as $row){
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo "{$row['id']}"; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "{$row['geslacht']}"; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "{$row['voornaam']}"; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "{$row['familienaam']}"; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "{$row['email']}"; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "{$row['tel']}"; ?></td>
            <td><a href="uploads/<?php echo "{$row['afile']}" ?>" target="_blank">view file</a></td>
            <td><?php echo "{$row['app_datum']}"; ?></td>
            <td class= "contact-profiel">
                <form action="profile.php"<?php echo "{$row['id']}"; ?> method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="idprofile" value="<?php echo "{$row['id']}"; ?>">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Profiel">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td class= "contact-delete">
                <form action="delete.php"<?php echo "{$row['id']}"; ?> method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo "{$row['id']}"; ?>">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
                </form>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <?php

    }



}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

Script 2

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" /></meta>

<head>
    <title>Zoek Formulier</title>
    <link href="styletest.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="table">

    <div class="tab-content">
        <h1>Zoek Formulier</h1>

        <form method="post" >

            <div class="top-row-search">
                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <label>Zoek Voornaam</label>
                    <input type="text" name="zoekvn" value="<?= isset($_POST['voornaam']) ? $_POST['voornaam'] : ''; ?>">
                </div> <!-- /field-wrap-->

                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <label>Zoek Familienaam</label>
                    <input type="text" name="zoekfn" value="">
                </div> <!-- /field-wrap-->

                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <label>Zoek email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="zoekem" value="">
                </div> <!-- /field-wrap-->

                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <label>Zoek tel</label>
                    <input type="text" name="zoektel" value="">
                </div> <!-- /field-wrap-->                                         

            </div> <!-- /top-row -->

            <button type="submit" class="button button-block" name="submit" />Zoek</button>

        </form> 

    </div><!-- /tab-content-->
</div><!-- /table-->

<br>

<div class="table">

    <div class="tab-content">
        <h1>Resultaten</h1>

        <form>

            <div id="body">
                <table width="100%" border="1">
                <tr>
                <th colspan="10">
                    <form action="search.php" method="post">
                        <input type="text" name="query" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Zoek" />
                    </form></th>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="10" color="#fff"><label><a href="test.php">Voeg nieuwe kandidaat toe</a></label></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete selected"></td></td>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>geslacht</td>
                <td>Voornaam</td>
                <td>Familienaam</td>
                <td>email</td>
                <td>Telefoon</td>
                <td>Bekijk CV</td>
                <td>Datum</td>
                <td>Profiel</td>
                <td>Verwijder</td>
            </tr>

        </form>

    </div><!-- /tab-content-->
</div><!-- /table-->
</body>
</html>


<?php

$servername = "xxxxx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxx";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])):

    try{
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, geslacht, voornaam, familienaam, email, tel, afile, app_datum FROM sollicitatie_form WHERE voornaam = ? or familienaam = ? or email = ? or tel = ?");

        $stmt->execute(array($_POST['zoekvn'], $_POST['zoekfn'], $_POST['zoekem'], $_POST['zoektel']));

        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        foreach ($result as $row){?>

        <form>

            <tr>
            <td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"></td>
            <td><?php echo "{$row['id']}"; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "{$row['geslacht']}"; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "{$row['voornaam']}"; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "{$row['familienaam']}"; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "{$row['email']}"; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "{$row['tel']}"; ?></td>
            <td><a href="uploads/<?php echo "{$row['afile']}" ?>" target="_blank">view file</a></td>
            <td><?php echo "{$row['app_datum']}"; ?></td>
            <td class= "contact-profiel">
                <form action="profile.php"<?php echo "{$row['id']}"; ?> method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="idprofile" value="<?php echo "{$row['id']}"; ?>">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Profiel">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td class= "contact-delete">
                <form action="delete.php"<?php echo "{$row['id']}"; ?> method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo "{$row['id']}"; ?>">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
                </form>
            </td>

        </tr>

        </form>


        <?php
        }
    }
        // use exec() because no results are returned
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
        }

$conn = null;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Just a side note `echo "{$row['id']}";` can be replaced by: `echo $row['id'];`. No need for the extra quotes and braces. That goes for all your echoes.

Comment: Just a note.CodeReview is for reviewing large amounts of code,but stack is for regular questions.It would be nice if you shrink your question ,and write it in a more clear way :D

Comment: @Arslan.H, of thanks, I was not aware of that. Sorry. I put in all my code as I'm not sure where the problem sits.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this line: `<form action="delete.php"<?php echo "{$row['id']}"; ?> method="post">`? That would result in something like this: `<form action="delete.php"2 method="post">`

Comment: You have forms inside of forms and links inside the forms that wont work with the form data. You really need to fix the HTML mark up first. You also need to simplify the code (e.g. delete all script 1 references)

Comment: @Arslan.H No. Code length is not the relevant factor for deciding whether a question belongs on Stack Overflow or Code Review. Rather, the issue is whether there is a specific issue to be solved (in which case the question belongs on Stack Overflow) or you are looking for non-specific improvements to working code (Code Review). Please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777).

Comment: @200_success thank you :D

Comment: @chris85, thanks, will fix my html mark up.